# EC2 instance is blocking all outbound connections, how to diagnose/fix?

Tags: amazon-ec2, outboundrules

My EC2 instance is blocking all outbound connections.

```
wget http://www.google.com  ==> Hangs
ping google.com ==>hangs
ssh user@anyserver ==>hangs
```

I ran : sudo iptables -F to eliminate all rules to no avail

AWS Management console shows Security Group for that instance has Inbound rule allowing ssh and port 80. Can't find anything about Outbound rules there.

Rebooted instance, no change.

If anyone knows how to diagnose or fix, please help.

Adding info:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-112-62-73 ~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:31:3D:06:31:BB  
          inet addr:10.112.62.73  Bcast:10.112.63.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1031:3dff:fe06:31bb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:164075 (160.2 KiB)  TX bytes:343256 (335.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:9 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:672 (672.0 b)  TX bytes:672 (672.0 b)


[ec2-user@ip-10-112-62-73 ~]$ ip route show
10.112.62.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.112.62.73 
default via 10.112.62.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: What if you `ping 8.8.8.8`?  Where are your DNS servers?

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8 ==> Hangs

Comment: Public DNS (from AWS Console): ec2-174-129-153-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Private DNS: ip-10-112-62-73.ec2.internal

Comment: log entries for your NIC? iptables -L?

Comment: iptables is clean since I ran iptables -F: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Not sure about log entries in NIC. How do I find out about that?

Comment: Look in /var/log for a log that has entries regarding network settings or issues.

Comment: looked in /var/log Lots of files there, checked a few of the recently modified ones and nothing seems relevant.

Comment: Ok, output of `ifconfig` and `ip route show` would be useful (edit into your main answer so they're formatted.)

Comment: Ok, I launched a new EC2 instance which doesn't have this problem. I'll use that for now. If you have any ideas about the problem with this one, then let me know.

Comment: Well if it's merely academic now, then just ditch the instance, but the final test is to `ping 10.112.62.1` (the next hop).

Comment: ping 10.112.62.1 hangs. Oh well. Amazon must have done something to mess it up, I haven't touched this instance in a while and pretty sure it didn't have this issue before. I'll just use the new instance, only a handful of files to copy.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me...have tried all the things suggested here and nothing is working. Our setup has been working fine for 9 months and all of a sudden all outbound traffic has been blocked.

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved this issue on my EC2 instance. I had to update the security group configuration, adding:

1. An Outbound rule for all HTTP TCP traffic on port 80, from destination 0.0.0.0/0
2. An Outbound rule for all HTTPS TCP traffic on port 443, from destination 0.0.0.0/0

I probably removed these accidentally while troubleshooting a different problem.

Comment: Even if I add these, there's always an EC2 outbound rule (which I cannot seem to edit) that shows 0.0.0.0/0 to be DENY for "all traffic". How is that managed?

Comment: That rule is fixed by Amazon and cannot be edited. It's a fail-safe rule.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the future:
If you are having the same issue but you are sure that you have the correct security configuration, just detach the security group from the instance, and reattach it.

Comment: You can't just detach security group, one thing need to be attached each time. Anyway juggling groups didn't work for me.

Comment: This was my issue. Even though I updated the rules, for some reason they weren't being applied. Removing and re-adding the security group did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by dis-associating the elastic ip and then re-associating it.